# Allow user to register using django-all-auth even if the social account exists and then connect the two automatically

Tags: django-allauth, django-rest-auth

So, I have been able to connect social accounts (fb or google) to be connected to the local email account if already exists.

However, I also want the reverse functionality, i.e. I would like to allow user to sign up even if the (google or FB) social account exists. Currently it says:

**{ A user is already registered with this email address }**

I am using django-all-auth and django-rest-auth with Django 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You should be able to modify the [password reset endpoint](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_endpoints.html) provided by `django-rest-auth` to set a password and then be able to login:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm as DjangoPasswordResetForm
from rest_auth.serializers import (
    PasswordResetSerializer as RestAuthPasswordResetSerializer
)
from rest_auth.views import PasswordResetView as RestAuthPasswordResetView

UserModel = get_user_model()


class PasswordResetForm(DjangoPasswordResetForm):
    def get_users(self, email):
        """
        Given an email, return matching user(s) who should receive a reset.
        """
        active_users = UserModel._default_manager.filter(**{
            '%s__iexact' % UserModel.get_email_field_name(): email,
            'is_active': True,
        })
        return iter(active_users)
        # or (u for u in active_users if not u.has_usable_password())


class PasswordResetSerializer(RestAuthPasswordResetSerializer):
    password_reset_form_class = PasswordResetForm


class PasswordResetView(RestAuthPasswordResetView):
    serializer_class = PasswordResetSerializer
```

You can add this view to your `urls.py` as general endpoint to reset passwords (remember to place it in front of the `rest_auth`s' URLs) or as an additional endpoint to set passwords (see the commented line). Then you can add a note to your signup page that links to your page that serves your new endpoint.

As an alternative, you could also add a field to your user settings page where users can set a password.

You could also send an e-mail with a link via [`send_confirmation`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/models.py#L55) to set a password when a user tries to sign up and the e-mail exists already (or only in case this user has a social account). If you like I could add an example here how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Password reset endpoint doesn't send emails with /password/reset endpoint when social account exists. However the same works if already registered with email.

Comment: An example will be really helpful. :)

Comment: @AnujVerma I had a look at the source code and hopefully found the reason why it doesn't work. See my updated answer for an example implementation.

Comment: Yofee, Thanks, it worked. Just as I needed! I have upvoted your answer but it is not visible as I am new here.

I am assuming this view does not interfere with any other endpoints? Is it safe to override the existing endpoint without fearing the loss of any functionality? Disclaimer: I am new to Django, therefore asking prudent questions.

Comment: The checkbox near the vote buttons is made for accepting an answer that solved your question (you even get some points if you do so). :) It should be safe to just override the existing endpoint because the [documentation in the Django code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9410db968388820e43aa453a640dd4720fff0c0f/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L260) says that you can override the `get_users` method exactly for that reason.